# How to pass JavaScript variables to React component

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I'm somewhat new to React and I'm having some trouble passing some variables from my Django server to my React components. Here's what I have:

The server is Django, and I have a url mydomain.com/testview/ that gets mapped to a views.py function testview:

```
def testview(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'testview.html', {
        'foo': '%s' % str(now),
        'myVar': 'someString'
    })
```

In other words, running testview will render the template file testview.html and will use the variables foo and myVar.

The file testview.html inherits from base.html which looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

The file test.html basically inserts the needed code into block main:

testview.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

{% block main %}
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = {{ foo }};  
var myVar = {{ myVar }};  
</script>
<div id="App"></div>
{% render_bundle 'vendors' %}
{% render_bundle 'App' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Note that just before the div id="App", I created a couple of javascript variables foo and myVar and set them to the values from Django.

Now to REACT: my file App.jsx looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "react-dom"

import AppContainer from "./containers/AppContainer"

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer foo={props.foo} myVar={props.myVar}/>
    )
  }
}

render(<App foo={window.foo} myVar={window.myVar}/>, document.getElementById('App'))
```

In other words, my App.jsx file renders the App component, passing in foo and myVar. Inside class App, I assumed these were props so I pass these to AppContainer using props.foo and props.myVar. My class AppContainer is inside a components folder and looks like this:

```
import React from "react"

import Headline from "../components/Headline"

export default class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <Headline>Running App! foo is {props.foo}, Here is a string: {props.myVar}</Headline>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, none of this seems to work. I just get a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, Marc, try removing the `window` from the variables in the last line of your `App.jsx` file: `render(<App foo={foo} myVar={myVar}/>, document.getElementById('App'))`. You created them as globals, so they are accessible just by their names. No need for `window.`.

Comment: try to alert foo value after this line , var foo = {{ foo }};

Answer (score 1):

if foo and myVar is string you should declare

```
var foo = "{{ foo }}";  
var myVar = "{{ myVar }}";
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I needed to do to get it to work. First, I used Giang Le's answer above and in my testview.html file (a Django template file), I put quotes around the variables as they were indeed strings. Next, I changed the render statement in my App.jsx file to be this:

```
render(<App foo={foo} myVar={myVar}/>, document.getElementById('App'))
```

This used Bruno Vodola Martins' answer to access foo and myVar as javascript globals. I also had to use this.props.foo instead of props.foo in my App class:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer foo={this.props.foo} myVar={this.props.myVar}/>
    )
  }
}
```

And I did the same thing in containers/AppContainer.jsx:

```
export default class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <Headline>App! foo is {this.props.foo}, Here is a string: {this.props.myVar}</Headline>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Bottom line: put quotes around string variables from Django, and use this.props.foo instead of just props.foo.