# passing data from django view context dictionary to react components

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I am trying to create a `Django` and `React` full-stack web app, using the Django Rest framework to create APIs. It is really easy to work with these two when it comes to sending data, but for the login and logout system it is becoming really messy to work with, as we cannot get the request user from a normal fetch request from React. As well as this, passing data from a view context dictionary to React is also getting too much difficult for me. I have a view to render `index.html` whose control is taken over by React, and I want to send whether the user is authenticated or not to my React component. How can I do that?

Here is what my view looks like:

```
def index(request):
    authenticated = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        authenticated = True
    context = {
        'authenticated':authenticated
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

I want to pass the value of `authenticated` to my React component. How can I do that? I have passed it to normal js on `index.html`, but don't know how to pass it to the React component.

Here is what index.html looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8" />
           <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
           <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
           <meta
               name="description"
               content="Web site created using create-react-app"
           />
           <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
          
           <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
   
           <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"> 
           <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin> 
           <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
           family=Encode+Sans+Expanded:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
           <title>React App</title>
           <script>
               var authenticated = "{{authenticated}}"
               console.log(authenticated)
           </script>
      </head>
      <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
     </body>
     </html>
```

The console is showing me 'True', but how can I pass it to my `App.js` file of React?

Answer (score 0):

**The are several ways to pass Django variables to react component :**

1. **Without request call :**
   Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149852/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-react-component), it will help you.
2. **with request call, like API or other endpoints :**

In your `views.py` file

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def is_authenticated(request):
    authenticated = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        authenticated = True
    data = {
        'authenticated':authenticated
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

in your `app.js` file

```
async function IsAuthenticated() {
    // Change the url to fit your needs
    const url = 'http//127.0.0.1:8000/';
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        // Do some stuff with data dict
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```